# Sublime Text 2: how to change white space characters color?

Tags: whitespace, sublimetext

The color seems to be linked to the foreground in themes. I assume it's using less alpha. Is there a way to control this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's now a Sublime plugin for this.

1. Install the [HighlightWhitespaces](https://github.com/disq/HighlightWhitespaces) plugin
2. Add the following color settings (tailored to your preference) to your color_scheme file. This file ends in `.tmTheme` and the path can be found by looking at the value for the key "color_scheme" in your settings file.

   ```
   <dict>
     <key>name</key>
     <string>highlight.whitespace</string>
     <key>scope</key>
     <string>highlight.whitespace</string>
     <key>settings</key>
     <dict>
       <key>background</key>
       <string>#020202</string>
       <key>foreground</key>
       <string>#805050</string>
     </dict>
   </dict>
   ```
3. Specify that this color should be used by adding the following to the user settings of the HighlightWhitespaces plugin:

   ```
   {
       "highlight_whitespaces_space_highlight_scope_name": "highlight.whitespace",
       "highlight_whitespaces_tab_highlight_scope_name": "highlight.whitespace",
       "highlight_whitespaces_eol_highlight_scope_name": "highlight.whitespace",
       "highlight_whitespaces_mixed_highlight_scope_name": "highlight.whitespace"
   }
   ```
4. Relax and enjoy :-)

Comment: Where is theme file?

Comment: @fechidal89: Now that I'm looking back at my answer, point 2 should have said 'add the color settings to your color scheme file'. So, go to menu `preferences->settings` and look at the value associated to "color_scheme" (confusingly the file name ends in .tmTheme), it is within this file that the color settings should be added. Go to the menu `preferences->Browse Packages` to open the packages folder, the "color_scheme" path will point to a file underneath this folder. For me it's: "color_scheme": "Packages/User/SublimeLinter/Monokai-Dev (SL) Jim's edit.tmTheme"

Comment: For Sublime 3, the color is stored in different place. For Mac OS it's store in /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages under Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package file name.
For safety reason, you need to copy the file to somewhere else, unzip it, edit it, backup the original file and replace with your edited file.

Comment: jimr, what is the difference between `background` and `foreground` in your item 2? May you make screenshot, that users to see difference? Likely, these keys represent a similar behavior. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try installing [PersistentRegexHighlight](https://github.com/skuroda/PersistentRegexHighlight) from Package Control and then use a blank-character regex like `[\x20 ]` to add a specific color or color scope.

You'd want to combine this with `drawWhiteSpace: "all",` in Sublime user prefs.

Comment: Spaces anywhere, or, tabs anywhere:  "pattern": " +|\t+",

Comment: The setting is now: `draw_white_space`.

Comment: `draw_white_space` has three values: `none`, `selection` (default), and `all`

Answer (score 3):

You can change the tab underline alpha by [changing the foreground alpha](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6161#p27030).

To change the color of spaces requires [changes to every syntax file](https://github.com/ckovey/sublime-whitespace-coloring).

Comment: foreground alpha seems to affect tabs, and also line numbers (but not spaces)

Answer (score 2):

A few years later, I was struggling with this in Sublime Text 3 build 3083. I hope this helps anyone. In addition to Chris Like's suggestion to install [PersistentRegexHighlight](https://github.com/skuroda/PersistentRegexHighlight) and setting `"draw_white_space": "all"` in the user preferences and the pattern to one or more occurances of tabs and spaces, i.e. `[ \t]+` in the PersistentRegexHighlight user settings, i had to also also set `"color_scope": "highlight.whitespace"` and add the following **dict** to the theme along with the other ones in the **settings** array:

```
<dict>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>highlight.whitespace</string>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>highlight.whitespace</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>background</key>
    <string>#020202</string>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#805050</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

which by the way oddly only outlines in red if the **background is set to black**, i.e **#000000**

Note that this method does not require editing any syntax files.