# Change apparance of whitespace dot to something bigger / darker

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am looking for a way to change the appearance of the whitespace grey dot to something bigger and darker (**without** changing the background color) -- similar to UltraEdit (see screenshot).

I've read all the popular threads on the issue, and I've tried all the popular modifications (e.g., plugins, and/or changing the language and theme files), but I haven't found a way to darken the grey dot or make it any bigger.

I've already experimented with everything mentioned in this related thread, including the links set forth therein:  [Sublime Text 2: how to change white space characters color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297068/sublime-text-2-how-to-change-white-space-characters-color)

---

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/dot_comparrison.png))</sub>

---

.tmTheme

```
<!-- BEGIN whitespace / tab definitions -->
<dict>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>lawlist.tab</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>fontStyle</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#FF0000</string>
    <key>background</key>
    <string>#FFFFFF</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
<dict>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>lawlist.space</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>fontStyle</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#000000</string>
    <key>background</key>
    <string>#FFFFFF</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
<!-- END whitespace / tab definitions -->
```

---

.tmLanguage

```
<!-- BEGIN whitespace / tab definitions -->
<dict>
  <key>match</key>
  <string>\t+</string>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>lawlist.tab</string>
</dict>

<dict>
  <key>match</key>
  <string> +</string>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>lawlist.space</string>
</dict>
<!-- END -->
```

Comment: A screenshot of what you are trying to describe would be helpful.

Comment: Good idea -- thank you.  I have added a screenshot and edited the question to make it a little bit easier to visualize what I'm seeking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Someone bumped a post on the ST forum about coloring white space and I thought of this post. You may see it too, but just in case, I'll post here. Basically they modified the tmLanguage file to give a new scope to leading whitespace. They then applied a color to that.

https://github.com/ckovey/sublime-whitespace-coloring

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I'm essentially using that same system now -- hard-coded into the theme and language files.  The above ST2 screenshot is the darkest setting for the foreground of `space+` (i.e., #000000) -- it is barely visible.  Changing the background of `space+` creates a large visible rectangle around the center dot, which is a little distracting when viewing surrounding text.  Ideally, a larger and/or darker dot would do the trick -- however, I haven't yet found a way to reach that result.  I'll add my code to the question.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I should have looked at the stackoverflow question you linked, since it's listed there too. Was that in the original post? I can't remember. Odd that the darkest foreground setting wouldn't be very visible though (on a white(ish) background)

Comment: I think that I've essentially tried everything that is Google-able, including your own plugin to underline the spaces (which only works for very small files).  I appreciate having a programmer of your caliber reading my post.  The link blended in the with screenshot, so I'll edit the question to put a little more space there.