# Highlighting tab characters in Sublime Text (2 or 3)

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Is there a way I can highlight just tab characters?  I know about `"draw_white_space": "all"` but I don't want to highlight all whitespace, just tabs.

There doesn't seem to be a plugin or a setting that fits the bill.  I'd like to avoid writing a new plugin, but I will if I have to.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't worked on this plugin in a while, but you can try [PersistentRegexHighlight](https://github.com/skuroda/PersistentRegexHighlight). You will just need to define a regex pattern for the tabs and a color to highlight with if you don't like the default.

Answer (score 1):

I have only tested this on SublimeText2.  As an alternative to PersistentRegexHighlight, you could use the following minor modifications to the theme and language files.  Please feel free to disregard / remove the whitespace definitions -- I included them because someone else may be interested in seeing how to modify Theme / Language files:

Excerpt from whatever language syntax you want -- e.g., LaTeX.tmLanguage

```
<!-- BEGIN whitespace / tab definitions -->
<dict>
  <key>match</key>
  <string>\t+</string>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>lawlist.tab</string>
</dict>

<dict>
  <key>match</key>
  <string> +</string>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>lawlist.space</string>
</dict>
<!-- END -->
```

Excerpt from whatever theme you are using -- e.g., lawlist.tmTheme

```
<!-- BEGIN whitespace / tab definitions -->
<dict>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>lawlist.tab</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>fontStyle</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#FF0000</string>
    <key>background</key>
    <string>#FFFFFF</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
<dict>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>lawlist.space</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>fontStyle</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#000000</string>
    <key>background</key>
    <string>#FFFFFF</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
<!-- END whitespace / tab definitions -->
```

Comment: That's a good idea. I'm pretty sure you were asking a similar question before. Anyways, this should work in ST3 also. However, you will need to override the existing file as it isn't in the Packages folder, as in ST2. However, I've written a plugin to make this easy also. [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer) will allow you to navigate packages and open files. When you save, it will place them in the correct location to override the existing file.

Comment: Yes, that was me:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918092/change-apparance-of-whitespace-dot-to-something-bigger-darker   Thank you for the tip about the PackageResourceViewer plugin for ST3.